How could one create a hash fingerprint for a computer's architecture/instruction set?
Imagine a protocol where participants sign a schema document to declare which version they will follow.
To define functions used in the protocol, without recourse to URLs, we could define operating systems by the SHA256 digest of their .iso/.img and then define the functions; something like this:
OS image hash digests
********************************
#OPENBSD : 0x034435c6e27405d5a7fafb058162943c194eb793dafdc412c08d49bb56b3892a
********************************

Function definitions:
********************************
RIPEMD160(ARG0) is the result of `$ARG0 | openssl ripemd160 -binary` on the default shell of #OPENBSD on amd64 architecture.
********************************

However, my concern is that amd64 architecture is too ambiguous. Perhaps it'd be possible to have different results with different instances of architecture A; where A is amd64 in the example. Am I correct in this concern? Of course, functions other than ripemd160 would be defined too.
Is there a hash fingerprint I could use to encapsulate "the machine that the OS is running on"? Perhaps a hash of a specification document could be used. If so, what document(s) would be good? Perhaps the riscv64 instruction set has advantages in this regard.

Hash the output of uname -mpi?
